# How does one modify layout that's used multiple times programmaticaly?

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I have two xml layout files, first one is a simply relative layout with other 7 relative layouts acting as columns and 7 views acting as separators. Each of column layout is using linear layout with multiple views that's placed in separate xml file as background. Here are layouts:

Container:

```
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/calendarRelativeLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="0dp" >             

            <View
                android:layout_width="0.5dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:background="@color/Gray"/>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/sundayRelativeLayout"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2" >

                <include layout="@layout/day_background" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="0.5dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:background="@color/Gray"/>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/mondayRelativeLayout"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2" >

                <include layout="@layout/day_background" />
            </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Background layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/day_background"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="52dp"
android:layout_height="1440dp"
android:background="@color/LightGray">

<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0.5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:background="@color/Gray" />
<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0.5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="59dp"
    android:background="@color/Gray" /></LinearLayout>
```

I shortened both of them because they would be to long, so that's why there are just two columns. I also don't have idea why is the editor cutting  tag in the end so I had to put it this way. I'm trying to modify that background layout width in container code but the problem's that's only first column background is getting changed, the rest stays with 52dp no mather what I do. I'm modyfing layout width using this:

```
    LinearLayout dayBackground = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.day_background);
    dayBackground.getLayoutParams().width = SystemHelper.getDayColumnWidth();
    dayBackground.requestLayout();
```

Here's is the screen from emulator, that's how it does look like:
[Emulator screen](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ip8zn6bc3fafdy5/disIsSomeBullshit.png)

What could be the problem?

Comment: *What could be the problem?* - most likely your doing your `findViewById(R.id.day_background)` calls in the activity which will **only** return the **first** occurrence of that view. So you'll need to iterate over child Relativelayouts of the `calendarRelativeLayout` RelativeLayout and use findViewById(R.id.day_background) on those references. Keep in mind that layout_weight is useless in a parent RelativeLayout so you shouldn't use a width of `0dp`. In the end you could probably build that table much cleaner and efficient than how you do it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luksprog advice was correct. FindViewById was getting first occurence of day_background layout. So instead I modified the code to use findViewById on RelativeLayouts which contained day_background layout. Here's the code:

```
RelativeLayout sundayRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.sundayRelativeLayout);
LinearLayout sundayDayBackground = (LinearLayout)sundayRelativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.day_background);
RelativeLayout mondayRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mondayRelativeLayout);
LinearLayout mondayDayBackground = (LinearLayout)mondayRelativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.day_background);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar issue in my case a few days back.I was having an `imageview` with some image over it.I was running the project successfully,However at some point i needed to  change the image in the `imageview` and add a smaller image to the imageview.When i added it, i was surprised that the old image was still there on my imageview and my new image(which was small as compared to the first one) was showing on the top of the old one.I tried everything to remove the older one from back  but in vain,Then i just **removed that** `imageview` and **recreated it** with the same attributes and new image.Fortunately it worked for me.There was no other way i was able to get rid of that under lying image which was appearing even when no image was set on the `imagview`